# Regex breaking my model: Regex is using multiline anchors (^ or $)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am updating a regex in my `Users` model, which seems to have broken it.  Whenever I try to do anything with the `Users` model, I get this error message:

> The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (`^` or `$`),
>   which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use `\A` and `\z`, or
>   forgot to add the `:multiline => true` option?

The problem arises under the email validation. My `User` model looks like:

```
require 'digest'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :format => { :with => /^[^@][\w.-]+@[\w.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}$/i }, ...
  ...
end
```

Comment: So replace `/^[^@][\w.-]+@[\w.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}$/i ` with `/\A[^@][\w.-]+@[\w.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\z/i `. You need to validate the whole string, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RoR, you need to explicitly tell the engine the boundaries, either `^`  and `$` with `:multiline => true` option to match lines or use `\A` and `\z` to match whole strings.

So, replace

```
/^[^@][\w.-]+@[\w.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}$/i
```

with

```
/\A[^@][\w.-]+@[\w.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\z/i
```

This allows unambiguous validation and reduces human error.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much.  I know it was kind of a duplicate question, but the substitutions weren't working out for me in the other answers.  My application is working again and I'm continuing through the book.  You're my savior!!